# Is it possible to make “unknown custom element” warnings into compilation errors?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

We’re doing some refactoring from globally-loaded components to locally-loaded components, and running into lots of random warnings with components now not being loaded, only when the components are loaded into the browser.

Is it possible to turn these warnings into compile-time errors, so we can fix them all in one sweep?

Comment: Should not these be cough by ESLint ?